# Sutta request: One should be fed before being able to listen to a Dhamma talk

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, texts, tipitaka

[The following quote can be found at this link:](https://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/aa/aalavii.htm)

> On the farmer's arrival the Buddha ordered that some food should be given him, and when the man was comforted and his mind was ready the Buddha preached a sermon, at the end of which the man became a Sotāpanna (DhA.iii.262-3).

I'm interested in finding out what **"DhA.iii.262-3"** means. I looked up the Dhammapada Verse 262-263 and they are about something else entirely. Screenshot of these verses are attached.

So where is the above story found in the Sutta Pitaka?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next line says,

> On another occasion the Buddha came all the way from Jetavana to ālavī for the sake of a weaver's daughter. (For the story see DhA.iii.170f).

The story of the Weaver's daughter is [on Access to Insight](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/burlingame/wheel324.html#sect24) on a page titled:

- *Buddhist Stories from the Dhammapada Commentary
  Part II
  translated from the Pali by
  E.W. Burlingame*

So the "DhA" may be that, i.e. not the Dhammapada but rather Buddhaghosa's commentary.

"DhA.iii" is presumably [Part 3 of 4](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/burlingame/index.html) -- but different publishers or translators have different ways to number volumes, but anyway, I assume it's from that commentary:

> In the fifth century the great Pali scholar-monk Buddhaghosa wrote an extensive commentary to the much-beloved Dhammapada. His commentary provides background stories that set the stage for each brief verse, giving them an expansive context that greatly enriches their meaning. The present booklet is the second in a four-part anthology.

[This comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/47703/find-sutta-eat-first-before-hearing-the-teaching#comment76406_47704) indicates it's the story to accompany verse 203.

Comment: Thank you so much.